# jquery .on() only works on lower version of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to work on adding text fields by clicking button.
In Jquery 2.2 version and below my code works fine, but when I use the recent version (3.1) and click the button to add field, nothing happens.

Here is my JavaScript.

```
 $(function() {
    var newTextFieldDiv = $('#newTextField');
    var i = $('#newTextField p').size() +1;

    $(document).on('click', '#addField', function() {
        $('<p><input type="text" name="fileName[]' + i +'" id="fileName" size="50" /><a href="#" id="removeButton">remove</a></p>').appendTo(newTextFieldDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#removeButton', function() { 
        if( i > 2 ) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

kindly see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Earrold/8uca2n4x/) to test

Thanks.

Comment: *"kindly see this fiddle to test"* Kindly use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) so runnable demos are *on-site*.

Comment: Not reproducible even on the JSFiddle - seems to be adding fields fine

Answer (score 3):

If you look in your web console, you'll see this error using jQuery 3.x:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).size is not a function

This is because the `size()` function was [deprecated in v1.8](http://api.jquery.com/size/), and removed entirely in 3.0. Use `.length` (a non-function property) insead. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uca2n4x/2/) with that fix applied.

Comment: so it's not on the "on() function". thanks on the update.